# Using regex to match adjacent words using first letter of abbreviations in text python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of abbreviations that I am trying to find in my text using regex. However I am struggling to find adjacent words by matching letters and have only achieved this with word matching. Here is my text

```
text = '''They posted out the United States Navy Seals (USNS) to the area.
Entrance was through an underground facility (UGF) as they has to bypass a no-fly-zone (NFZ).
I found an assault-rifle (AR) in the armoury.'''
```

My list is as such: `[USNS, UGF, NFZ, AR]`

I would like to find the corresponding long forms in the text using the first letter of each abbreviation. It would also need to be non-case sensitive. My attempt so far has been as such:

`re.search(r'\bUnited\W+?States\b\W+?Navy\b\W+?Seals\b', text)` 
which returns United States Navy Seals however when I try and just use the first letter:

`re.search(r'\bU\W+?S\b\W+?N\b\W+?S\b', text)`

It then returns nothing. Furthermore some of the abbreviations contain more than the initial of a word in the text such as UGF - underground facility.

My actual goal is to eventually replace all abbreviations in the text (*USNS*, *UGF*, *NFZ*, *AR*) with their corresponding long forms (*United States Navy Seals*, *underground facility*, *no-fly-zone*, *assault-rifle*).

Comment: Could you please explain what your expected output should look like for the provided sample string? Should the `(full form)` be a part of the returned match? Or, should these short forms be excluded from the results? Can we assume there can be no 1-letter words in the long forms?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated the question to show expected outputs.

Comment: @Wolf My end goal is to find the long forms and replace abbreviations in the text.

Comment: No replace the abbreviations with the long form.

Comment: @geds133 I updated your question according to your explanations in comments. Please have a look: Does it reflect correctly your intent now?

Comment: What rule would tell us that "UGF" is an acronym for "underground facility"?

Answer (score 3):

In your last regex <sup>[1]</sup>

```
re.search(r'\bU\W+?S\b\W+?N\b\W+?S\b', text)
```

you get no match because you made several mistakes:

- `\w+` means one or more word characters, `\W+` is for one or more non-word characters.
- the `\b` boundary anchor is sometimes in the wrong place (i.e. between the initial letter and the rest of the word)

```
re.search(r'\bU\w+\sS\w+?\sN\w+?\sS\w+', text)
```

should match.

And, well,

```
print(re.search(r'\bu\w+?g\w+\sf\w+', text))
```

matches of course `underground facility` but in a long text, there will be much more irrelevant matches.

#### Approach to generalization

Finally I built a little "machine" that dynamically creates regular expressions from the known abbreviations:

```py
import re

text = '''They posted out the United States Navy Seals (USNS) to the area.
Entrance was through an underground facility (UGF) as they has to bypass a no-fly-zone (NFZ).
I found an assault-rifle (AR) in the armoury.'''

abbrs = ['USNS', 'UGF', 'NFZ', 'AR']

for abbr in abbrs:
    pattern = ''.join(map(lambda i: '['+i.upper()+i.lower()+'][a-z]+[ a-z-]', abbr))
    print(pattern) 
    print(re.search(pattern, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

The output of above script is:

```
[Uu][a-z]+[ a-z-][Ss][a-z]+[ a-z-][Nn][a-z]+[ a-z-][Ss][a-z]+[ a-z-]
<re.Match object; span=(20, 45), match='United States Navy Seals '>
[Uu][a-z]+[ a-z-][Gg][a-z]+[ a-z-][Ff][a-z]+[ a-z-]
<re.Match object; span=(89, 110), match='underground facility '>
[Nn][a-z]+[ a-z-][Ff][a-z]+[ a-z-][Zz][a-z]+[ a-z-]
<re.Match object; span=(140, 152), match='no-fly-zone '>
[Aa][a-z]+[ a-z-][Rr][a-z]+[ a-z-]
<re.Match object; span=(170, 184), match='assault-rifle '>
```

#### Further generalization

If we assume that in a text each abbreviation is introduced after the first occurrence of the corresponding long form, and we further assume that the way it is written definitely starts with a word boundary and definitely ends with a word boundary (no assumptions about capitalization and the use of hyphens), we can try to extract a glossary automatically like this:

```py
import re

text = '''They posted out the United States Navy Seals (USNS) to the area.
Entrance was through an underground facility (UGF) as they has to bypass a no-fly-zone (NFZ).
I found an assault-rifle (AR) in the armoury.'''

# build a regex for an initial
def init_re(i):
    return f'[{i.upper()+i.lower()}][a-z]+[ -]??'

# build a regex for an abbreviation
def abbr_re(abbr):
    return r'\b'+''.join([init_re(i) for i in abbr])+r'\b'

# build an inverse glossary from a text
def inverse_glossary(text):
    abbreviations = set(re.findall('\([A-Z]+\)', text))
    igloss = dict()
    for pabbr in abbreviations:
        abbr = pabbr[1:-1]
        pattern = '('+abbr_re(abbr)+') '+r'\('+abbr+r'\)'
        m = re.search(pattern, text)
        if m:
            longform = m.group(1)
            igloss[longform] = abbr
    return igloss

igloss = inverse_glossary(text)
for long in igloss:
    print('{} -> {}'.format(long, igloss[long]))
```

The output is

```
no-fly-zone -> NFZ
United States Navy Seals -> USNS
assault-rifle -> AR
underground facility -> UGF
```

By using an inverse glossary you may easily replace all long forms into their corresponding abbreviation. A bit harder is it to do for all but the first occurrence. There is much space for refinement, for example to correctly handle line breaks within long forms (also to use [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)).

As to replace the abbreviations with the long forms, you have to build a **normal glossary** instead of an inverse one:

```py
# build a glossary from a text
def glossary(text):
    abbreviations = set(re.findall('\([A-Z]+\)', text))
    gloss = dict()
    for pabbr in abbreviations:
        abbr = pabbr[1:-1]
        pattern = '('+abbr_re(abbr)+') '+r'\('+abbr+r'\)'
        m = re.search(pattern, text)
        if m:
            longform = m.group(1)
            gloss[abbr] = longform
    return gloss

gloss = glossary(text)
for abbr in gloss:
    print('{}: {}'.format(abbr, gloss[abbr]))
```

The output here is

```
AR: assault-rifle
NFZ: no-fly-zone
UGF: underground facility
USNS: United States Navy Seals
```

The [replacement](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) itself is left to the reader.

---

<sup>[1]</sup>
Let's take a closer look at your first regex again:

```
re.search(r'\bUnited\W+?States\b\W+?Navy\b\W+?Seals\b', text)
```

The boundary anchors (`\b`) are redundant. They can be removed without changing anything in the result because `\W+?` means at least one non-word character after the last character of `States` and `Navy`. They cause no problems here but I guess that they led to the confusion when you started by modifying from it to get a more general one.

Comment: re.search(r'\bU\w+\sG\w+?\sF\w+', text) doesn't find `underground facility`. Is my edited regex incorrect?

Comment: 'It would also need to be non-case sensitive' - As per the question, it would need to be case insensitive. Also even if I lower the cases, it still does not match 'underground facility`

Comment: This answer has found exactly what I am looking for. However is there a way to make it case insensitive in the re search?

Comment: the "machine" treats the initials case-insensitive

Comment: I am having a problems with solutions generalising. I have another short text I have run this on with different abbreviations and it returns nothing. Is there a way to share this text with you to show you the problem? I don't want to clog up the question.

Comment: Ignore above . Again, I'm not sure why but when running this on an unseen corpus t returns a dictionary with only 2 of 7 abbreviations.

Comment: The generalization (final one) is built on the assumption that the text has at least one place where the term is followed by its abbreviation in parentheses. If this is not the case, it finds nothing.

Comment: Which abbreviations + terms?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213511/discussion-between-geds133-and-wolf).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below regex which would take care of the case sensitivity as well. Click [here](https://regex101.com/r/uUNItW/2).

This would just find United States Navy Seals.

```
\s[u|U].*?[s|S].*?[n|N].*?[s|S]\w+
```

Similarly, for UF,
You can use - `\s[u|U].*?[g|G].*?[f|F]\w+`

Please find a pattern above. The characters are just joined with `.*?` and each character is used as `[a|A]` which would match either lower case or upper case. The start would be `\s` since it should be a word and the end would `\w+`.

Play around.

Comment: You are mixing up alteration `(?:a|b)` and character classes `[ab]`.

Comment: This pattern `\s[u|U].*?[g|G].*?[f|F]\w+` matches United States Navy Seals and not underground facility.

Comment: `[uU]` is the character class including lowercase and uppercase `u` -- the or is inclusive in the brackets. If you add `|` here, it's just another character, so `[u|U]` is the character class that consists of three characters: lowercase and uppercase `u` and `|`.